# Question about the type of `&"hello"` and `"hello"`

Tags: c++, c++17

As per the output of [this code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/9rzGe66vY), the type of `&"hello"` is `const char(*)[6]`, so `char* ptr = &"hello";` is inlegal for `char*` and `const char(*)[6]` are different types.

And since `char* ptr1 = "hello";` compiles with C++11 and latter, the type of `"hello"` is `char*`?

If the type of `"hello"` is `char*`, then `&"hello"` shouldn't be a pointer which points to `char*`(i.e. `char**`)?

I used to write `char* ptr1 = "hello";` many years, and when I know that "hello" is a prvalue. A question raises that I could acquire the address of the string literal.After I found the type of `&"hello"` is `const char(*)[6]`, I am totally confued now.

Could anybody shed some light on this matter?

Here is the aforementioned code snippet:

```
#include<memory>
#include<thread>
#include<iostream>
#include<typeinfo>

int main()
{
    char* ptr = &"hello";
    char* ptr1 = "hello";
}
```

Here is what the compiler complains:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:8:17: error: cannot convert 'const char (*)[6]' to 'char*' in initialization
    8 |     char* ptr = &"hello";
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
      |                 |
      |                 const char (*)[6]
<source>:9:18: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
    9 |     char* ptr1 = "hello";
      |                  ^~~~~~~
```

**UPDATE**:
Thanks to ShadowRanger's clarification. I realise that type of string literal is `const char[6]`.

Comment: `And since char* ptr1 = "hello"; is legal in C and C++11` That is false.  In C++, string literals have always been of type `const char[N]`

Comment: That is why you got the warning `warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]`

Comment: `char* ptr1 = "hello";` is legal in *C* (though pretty pointless, since if you write to it, you invoke undefined behavior anyway). Where do you get the idea it's legal in C++ (any version)?

Comment: @ShadowRanger For the said expression(i.e. `char* = "hello"`) compiles with C++11 and latter.

Comment: @John: "It compiles" does not mean legal. If you're running the compiler in relaxed modes (often the default), it allows a lot of stuff that isn't legal (or even close to it) according to the language spec. The warning is quite clear though; *no* standardized version of C++ has *ever* allowed a string constant to convert to a `char *`; they're *always* `const char[N]`, and if stored to a pointer, it must be stored to `const char *`. When the compiler allows it, it's usually some hamfisted attempt to allow code written for C to work when compiled as C++, but it is not legal C++ code.

Comment: @John When compiling with gcc or clang, use the `-pedantic-errors` compiler flag.  That will turn off all C extensions the compiler might implicitly have on and force strict C++ standard compliance.  Doing so here would stop this code from compiling.

Comment: `char* p= "hello;"` was valid in C++03 and earlier, though called out as deprecated. This was a special case in array-to-pointer standard conversion; the type of `"hello"` was already `const char[6]`. This compatibility feature is removed as of C++11.

Comment: "*And since `char* ptr1 = "hello";` compiles with C++11 and latter, the type of `"hello"` is `char*`?*" - no. The type of a string literal is `const char[N]`, which *decays* into a `const char*` pointer in some contexts. Some compilers allow assigning a string literal to a *non-const* `char*` pointer as a deprecated extension, but this is not legal in the C++11 standard and later.

Comment: Note that this behavior stems from a time deep in C history when many C library functions where not properly const qualified. For example you had `int strlen(char *)`. Also string literals weren't write protected by the hardware. Over time people learned how important `const` is and compilers placed string literals in the read-only data section. So modifying string literals became UB but passing them to those non-const library functions still had to work and we still live with that looseness today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"Hello"` is a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) of type `const char [6]` which **decays** to `const char*` due to **type decay**.

Now let's see what is happening for each of the statements in you program.

##### Case 1

Here we consider the statement:

```
char* ptr = &"hello";
```

As i said, `"hello"` is of type `const char [6]`. So, applying the address of operator `&` on it gives us a `const char (*)[6]` which is read as a *pointer to an array of size 6 with elements of type `const char`*.

This means that there is a mismatch in the type on the right hand side(which is `const char (*)[6]`) and the left hand side(which is `char*`). And since there is no implicit conversion from a `const char (*)[6]` to a `char*` the compiler gives the mentioned error saying:

```
cannot convert 'const char (*)[6]' to 'char*'
```

##### Case 2

Here we consider the statement:

```
char* ptr1 = "hello"; //invalid C++
```

Since `"Hello"` is of type `const char[6]`  meaning that the `char` elements inside the array are immutable(or non-changable). As i said, the type `const char[6]` decays to `const char*`. Thus on the right hand side we have a `const char*`. So if we were allowed to write `char* ptr1 = "Hello";` then that would mean that we're allowed to change the elements of the array since there is no low-level `const` on `ptr1`. Thus, allowing `char* ptr1 = "Hello";` would allow changing `const` marked data, which should not happen(since the data was not supposed to change as it was marked `const`).  This is why the mentioned warning said:

```
ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*'
```

So to prevent this from happening we have to add a low-level `const` as shown below:

```
vvvvv---------------------------> note the low-level const
const char* ptr1 = "Hello";  //valid c++
```

so that the pointer `ptr1` is not allowed to change the `const` marked data.
By adding the low-level `const` highlighted above, it is meant that we're not allowed to change the underlying characters of the array.

Comment: ***As i said, the type `const char[6]` decays to `const char*`. Thus on the right hand side we have a `const char*`.*** When the said decay occurs? I think it's when the assignment  operator is called other than *before the assignment  operator is called*. Am I right?

Comment: @John The decay happens before the assignment. Then after the decay happens, we have a `const char*` on the right hand side. Thus we're trying to assign a `const char*`(on the right hand side) to a `char*` on the left hand side and hence the mentioned warning.